# How to use the recycler view as a (tab layout) to update fragment layout with user info

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener, android-viewmodel

[I want to achieve this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjaNC.png)

My goal is that when user click on the person it the change the text color to blue and it will show the personal information and it will be same for all the users. so I am trying to use recycler view with single fragment.

when user clicks on the **Button Increment ** it will update the person count in recycler view.

when user switch between deferent person I want to show that person information without creating new fragment.

I tried using the tab layout and view-pager but the layout is same for all the users so I think there should be a better way to approach this.

should I pass viewmodle to my adapter and observe the button click count?

this problem has 3 main question.

1. should I pass the view model to update the recycler-view data?
2. how to approach when different person is click should I create new fragment and apply the data again or should I user single view model to show the person data?
3. how to hand click when user clicks on the increment button and how pass the data back to update the increment count in recycler view.

[Image to achieve this result

Comment: I was able to achieve this by using the live data to navigate between different passengers and once I select the current passenger, it will update the names and the information regarding that live data since live data is the lifecycle of it and it is event driven so it helps us to sync all the other data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes a simple way to start is to have 1 viewModel that is passed into the adapter and as well as to the fragment.

Let’s start simple and get it working with just 3 peoples data. In your view model you should then have:

> 

```
val person1 = mutableLiveData<Person>()
val person2 = mutableLiveData<Person>()
val person3 = mutableLiveData<Person>()

init {
    person1.value = Person()
    …
}
```

Then if you pass the viewModel to the the adapter, you can have:

```
veiwModel.person1.observe { updatedPerson ->
    dataset.removeAt(0)
    dataset.addItemAtPosotion(updatedPerson, 0)
    this@MyAdapterName.notifyItemChanged(0)
}
```

In your fragment you can similarly observe a new piece of live data call fragmentPerson and reinitialize the fragment when that data changes.

Comment: Let me know if you have questions, or please upvote/accept if its working for you

Answer (score 0):

So to achieve the exact same behaviour which you are looking for, you need to use a recyclerView with a ViewPager2.

In general we use ViewPager2 or ViewPager only with tab layout but we can use these also with recycler view or any other view which behaves like RecyclerView.

So the Question is how to do this,

Let's break it into steps,

**Step 1:**

- Create RecyclerView's item and adapter
- Now attach that adapter with the recyclerView (who's LayoutManager is
  Linear and orientation is horizontal)

Now you have recyclerView of exact same design what you want instead of tabs

**Step 2:**

Add a ViewPager2 tag in you XML just below to your recyclerView

Create an Adapter for ViewPager2 it will be like

```
class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {

        PagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fragmentManager, @NonNull Lifecycle lifecycle) {
            super(fragmentManager, lifecycle);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
            return FragmentYouWantToOpenWhenItemOnRVSelected.newInstance();
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return list.size();
        }
    }
```

Now create object of that PagerAdapter as

```
PagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), getLifecycle());
```

attach pagerAdapter with your ViewPager2 as

```
binding.viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
```

Now you are done with both RecyclerView and ViewPager

**Step 3:**

The only thing left is to open the specified Fragment in ViewPager when item is selected from recyclerView and ViceVersa

So your recyclerViewAdpater (The one you created in Step 1) must have a callback when an item is selected i.e.implemented as

```
 @Override
 public void selectedTab(int position) {
        binding.viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
        binding.viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
        binding.tabLayout.scrollToPosition(position);
        adapter.setTabPosition(position);
    }
```

in your activity or fragment (where your ViewPager2 and RecyclerView are)

Now when viewPager2 change the fragment on right or left swipe the recyclerView should also scroll to that item to achieve this you want below settings for ViewPager

```
public void tabSettings() {
        binding.viewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                binding.viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
                binding.viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
                int requiredPosition = globalPosition < position ? position + 1 : position - 1;
                try {
                    binding.tabLayout.scrollToPosition(requiredPosition);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    binding.tabLayout.scrollToPosition(position);
                }
                globalPosition = position;
                adapter.setTabPosition(position);
            }
        });
    }
```

the tabLayout named in above code is basically the recyclerView so don't confuse with name.

That's all you have implemented the ViewPager2 with recyclerView instead of TabLayout now.

Hopefully this will help you.

Comment: Will this be still useful, if I have single fragment, showing same thing for all the tabs ?

Comment: yes you can return same fragment all the time in PagerAdapter (Note: it could be same or new instance of fragment all the time)